# Enzyme error 'ShallowWrapper can only wrap valid elements' on shallow functional component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-functional-component

(I'm using React 16.11.0 and Enzyme 3.10)

I have a React.js state-less functional component in

```
Product.js     

import React from 'react';

export const Product = ({productName}) => { 
   return (
      <div>
          <span class='product-name'>{productName}</span>
      <div>
   );
```

which I'm trying to test using Enzyme Shallow like this
    Product.spec.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Product } from "./Product.js";

let props;

beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
        productName: "Bicycle"
    };
});

describe('Product', () => {
   it('should have productName', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Product {...props} />);
      expect(wrapper.find('.product-name').length).toEqual(1);
   });
}
```

but when the test runs, enzyme throws this error:

```
TypeError: ShallowWrapper can only wrap valid elements
```

If I rewrite the Product.js like this it works fine, so wonder why

```
function Product(props) { 
   return (
      <div>
          <span class='product-name'>{props.productName}</span>
      <div>
   );
export Product
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import your component in test file.

```
import {Product} from "./Product.js";
```

Comment: Good spot! My actual code already had that but I forgot to add to the question...I've updated it now. Thanks :)